# Matplotlib causes runtime error in pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, runtime-error

I have a problem with matplotlib when I am ploting multiple figures in pycharm IDE:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
num = 1 
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)#axarr[0, 0]
im1 = ax1.imshow(test[num][0], vmin=15,  cmap='gray', aspect='equal')
ax1.set_title("test title 1")
fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
im2 = ax2.imshow(test2[num][0], vmin=15,  cmap='gray', aspect='equal')
ax2.set_title("test title2")
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
im3 = ax3.imshow(test3[num][0], vmin=15,  cmap='gray',aspect='equal')
ax3.set_title("test title3")
fig.colorbar(im3, ax=ax3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)
im4 = ax4.imshow(test4[num][0], vmin=1300, vmax=1700, aspect='equal')
ax4.set_title("test tiltle 4")
fig.colorbar(im4, ax=ax4)
```

test1-4 arrayes are `ndarray:(700,1,256,256)`

The following error appears at a random time after single or multiple run of code added above:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7f1482693518>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3507, in __del__
     self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

and pycharm console returns following and freezes:

```
 Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Some posts suggested to use `matplotlib.use('Agg')` but I want the plot to be shown. I use `matplotlib 3.0.3`

Why this error happens at a random time and how can I resolve this?